# Good-enough practice for transplanting raspberry at not-ideal season

Tags: plant-health, transplanting, raspberries

I'm planning to transplant some raspberry canes during summer heat. I know normally raspberries should be transplanted in early spring or late fall when the plants are dormant, but I'm moving so it has to happen now. The plants have been yielding ripe fruit for a couple weeks, so they're on the late end of their production season.

What regimen can I follow for transplanting that will give the transplanted canes a decent shot of surviving the stress of a Summer move?

Answer (score 1):

In the long term the most important part of a raspberry plant is the roots. Everything else gets renewed every two years whatever happens.

To minimize water loss, cut down this year's fruiting canes as if you are pruning them early, and you might also consider reducing next year's canes to a minimum number, say 2 per plant. (But not just a single cane, in case it gets damaged during the move.) Don't shorten the new canes that you leave, otherwise you will remove the growing point at the tip.

If you can avoid the roots drying out while you transport them they should survive. For example you might be able to pack the roots into a container filled with soil instead of moving then as "bare rooted" plants.

After the move, give them lots of water for the rest of this year until they start to go dormant for the winter.

Comment: alephzero, thanks, but could you clarify what you mean by "next year's canes?"